# Use Git to only to check changes, without creating history

Tags: git

Is it possible to use Git in the following way?

1. Have some files in a directory structure which is considered clean by Git.
2. Change some files. Use `git diff` to see changes. Repeat this step as needed.
3. Finally, make Git consider changes from step 2 as "clean", *without creating history*.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 infinitely.

This is for local, single-user use only if that makes things easier.

Comment: Probably (eg revert brach to previous commit), but why would you want to do this? If you don't push any changes are purely local, so no one else will see them.

Comment: Commits are history. Also why would you want this and not have a history?

Comment: Isn’t that the reason for the stash?

Comment: Stashing is for making temporary changes. Stashing creates no history. - if you don’t want this, you can add like normal and amend the previous commit, or reset soft before each commit.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the original post. If you're referring to regular stashes, and they're not an answer to the question, because they will reset the tree to the original state, rather than considering the changed state as the "new, clean state".

Comment: @evolutionxbox *“Stashing creates no history”* – Stashing technically creates a history too. A stash is internally very similar to a commit.

Comment: @poke interesting I wonder if a stash has parent commits.

Comment: *"Finally, make Git consider changes from step 2 as "clean" state"* -- this is what `git add .; git commit` do. Use them!

Comment: @evolutionxbox It has! If you look at old stashes, e.g. using `git show stash@{0} -p`, you will only see its changes to its parent instead of its changes to the current HEAD.

Comment: sounds like what you want to do is make a branch and then `git rebase` it onto the original branch in a single commit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need only one commit.

Step 1,

```
git add .
git commit -m foo
```

Step 2,

```
#modify the files
git diff
```

Step 3,

```
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

After Step 3, you still have only one commit.

If you need to push the branch with only one commit to a remote repository for backup.

```
git push <remote> -f <branch>
```

Always use `-f` to force update the remote branch in this case.

Comment: That's a good way. Continuously amending to the initial branch will effectively yield a clean state and prevent an increasing history.

Comment: But it will modify existing history so it's imperative you know what that means. In essence, until you're done modifying that commit, don't push your commit to a central repository.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I guess OP takes this branch as a private one.

Comment: `git push -f` produces more problems than you have now, not only to you but especially to your coworkers.

Comment: @axiac From OP's needs, I don't think she/he will share the branch with others. Most likely just for backup.

Comment: Since when `git push` does not share?!

Comment: @axiac `git push` just transfers data to another repo. It does not guarantee the data will be shared with others.

Answer (score 2):

`git diff` will by default only compare the working directory against the current index (staging area). So what you can do is simply add the changes you want to keep without actually committing. That way, `git diff` will only pick up the changes you haven’t staged yet, but you don’t actually need to create a commit.

The only “downside” is that Git will not technically consider this “clean” and `git status` will still show all your staged changes.

Comment: Good point! Very good, actually. Because `git diff` will give an empty response after you `git add .`. The downside is that `git status` will show a chaotic, long list of changes since the initial commit. Oh, you already wrote that... Unless you were real quick and nicked it off me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --soft HEAD

git add --all

git commit -m "..."
```

Since we override history, -f is needed for commit:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Interesting... Will this, in effect, give the same result as amending (LPK's answer)?

Comment: The result for those who pull will be the same. But it gives you better overview of what has changed in this commit *in the sum* compared to the previous commit. Also you can use it if you think there was too many commits and want to collect/squash several commits into one. Then just reset not to HEAD, but to the desired revision and you will see all changes since then as a single modified set that you can commit now at once.

Comment: To your remark *without creating history*: If you mean *without increasing the number of commits in the history*, then the both  solutions with reset and with amend give that. And both of them *override* history, that&#39;s why both need *-f* for pushing.

Comment: `git push -f` produces more problems than you have now, not only to you but especially to your coworkers.

Comment: Not really. 1. This is the requirement of OP to override the history and -f is a consequence. 2. If you do that in your feature branch only, no coworkers are affected. 3. If you do that in the branch used by coworkers: if they prefer less merge efforts, -f is not perfect. But then coworkers get very detailed history and will waste time trying to get an overview of what was actually done. 4. That is s why some teams prefer a reasonable balance.

Comment: @axiac: why don't you downvote ALL the solutions here - they all need -f. And why don't you downvote the question just because it requires -f? Have opened a bug at git to prohibit -f?

Comment: This worked very well for me. I didn't use push, and don't know why I would. Also, I used a soft reset back to the initial commit to squash history that was amassed previously.

Comment: @mentallurg I **did** downvote all the answers that use `-f`. As you can see from OP's comment above, using `push`, with or without `-f` was not even part of the question. Your answer is not useful, it does not produce the expected outcome. Btw, [`git reset --soft HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft) is a no-op.

Comment: @axiac: right :) HEAD~1, HEAD~2 or particular revision.

Comment: @axiac: To downvoting: Yesss! I like your consistency :) *"Your answer is not useful, it does not produce the expected outcome"*: The OP said **"This worked very well for me."**. Regarding *push*: For some this is a matter of taste. But the most developers I know prefer to push regularly to the repository, which is backed up daily. In some of our environments, kind of "clean rooms", if your system account is not prolongated in time, then your VM is just automatically recycled the next day including your virtual HDD with all your code. So *pushing* is as natural as tooth brushing.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to hide the history of the changes (because you afraid that you make many try&error commit or because you prefer manay small vommits), there are other solutions.

- Create a branch.
- Commit to your branch as often as you need.
- Don't reverse commit with errors. Just fix the errors in the next commits.
- When you are ready and want that all your commits are displayed as a single commit in the history, you can use *squash* during merge or you can use *reset --soft* as described above.